# Jetpack Compose scrollable *only if needed*

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In a WearOS application¹ I need to display some - possibly long - text that should scroll beneath fixed header and footer. Easy:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ShowTextWithHeader(
    text: String,
    headerLine: String = "Header Line",
    footerLine: String = "Footer Line",
) {
    val listState = rememberScrollState(0)

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        positionIndicator = { PositionIndicator(listState) },
    ) {
        Box {
            PossiblyScrollableText(text, listState, 30.dp, 30.dp)
            Header(headerLine, 30.dp)
            Footer(footerLine, 30.dp)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun PossiblyScrollableText(
    text: String,
    listState: ScrollState,
    headerHeight: Dp,
    footherHeight: Dp,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,

        ) {
        Text(
            text,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = headerHeight)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(listState)
                .padding(bottom = footherHeight)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun BoxScope.Header(
    line: String,
    height: Dp,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(height)
            .background(Color.Gray)
            .align(Alignment.TopCenter),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    ) {
        Text(line)
    }
}

@Composable
private fun BoxScope.Footer(
    line: String,
    height: Dp,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(height)
            .background(Color.Gray)
            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    ) {
        Text(line)
    }
}

@Preview(widthDp = 200, heightDp = 150, backgroundColor = 0xff000000, showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PreviewLongText() {
    ShowTextWithHeader(
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
    )
}
```

The output (the position indicator is working correcly, though I couldn't capture a screenshot with it):

[image: Long text scrollable beneath fixed header and footer]

---

Now the problem with the above implementation appears when the text is not long enough:

```kotlin
@Preview(widthDp = 200, heightDp = 150, backgroundColor = 0xff000000, showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PreviewShortText() {
    ShowTextWithHeader(
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
    )
}
```

Which gives:

[image: Short text -- needlessly scrollable -- between fixed header and footer]

The output is not too bad. For a webpage for instance, I would be happy with it. But for a small viewport, I'd rather have the text centralized and not scrollable at all, like this:

[image: Short text unscrollable under fixed header]

Which I achieved by removing all modifiers from the text:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun PossiblyScrollableText(text: String) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ) {
        Text(text)
    }
}
```

If these alternative layouts would change over some computable pre condition, it would be easy to implement using `ifs`. But the condition is intrinsic: the size of rendered text being bigger than the visible space (entire viewport minus header and footer heights).

**NB**: this code is not my final code. The final code has more padding, and styling, and sober colors and so on. The code here is just my effort to a **Minimal** Reproducible Example.

¹I only mention WearOS as rationale for such a small screen. I think that the problem described applies to Jetpack Compose broadly. Correct me if this assumption is wrong.